# Nexus OSS not starting after adding the R repository plug-in (me too)

Tags: r, nexus, nexus3

Nexus OSS 3.10.0-04 running on RHEL 6. I am referring to the ['permanent install'](https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-r#most-permanent-install) section of the R plug-in.

After compiling the plugin I copied it in `/system/org/sonatype/nexus/plugins/nexus-repository-r/1.0.1/nexus-repository-r-1.0.1.jar`

I added the following entries in the `system/org/sonatype/nexus/assemblies/nexus-core-feature/3.10.0-04/nexus-core-feature-3.10.0-04-features.xml` as the exact path : `/system/com/sonatype/nexus/assemblies/nexus-oss-feature/3.x.y/nexus-oss-feature-3.x.y-features.xml` does not exist.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.4.0" name="nexus-core-feature">
    <feature name="nexus-core-feature" description="org.sonatype.nexus.assemblies:nexus-core-feature" version="3.10.0.04">
        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.assemblies:nexus-core-feature</details>
        <feature version="3.10.0.04" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-audit-plugin</feature>
        <feature version="3.10.0.04" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-blobstore-tasks</feature>
        <feature version="3.10.0.04" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-ssl-plugin</feature>
        <feature version="3.10.0.04" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-coreui-plugin</feature>
        <feature version="3.10.0.04" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-httpbridge</feature>
        <feature version="3.10.0.04" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-maven</feature>
        <feature version="3.10.0.04" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-raw</feature>
        <feature version="3.10.0.04" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-restore-maven</feature>
        <feature version="3.10.0.04" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-script-plugin</feature>
        <feature version="3.10.0.04" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-task-log-cleanup</feature>
+       <feature version="1.0.1" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-r</feature>
        <feature prerequisite="true" dependency="false">wrap</feature>
        ...
+   <feature name="nexus-repository-r" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-r" version="1.0.1">                     
+    <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-r</details>                                             
+     <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-repository-r/1.0.1</bundle>                                    
+   </feature>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
</features>
```

Nexus does not start and I have the following error in nexus.log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=nexus-core-feature; type=karaf.feature; version=0; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=nexus-core-feature)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=0.0.0))" [caused by: Unable to resolve nexus-core-feature/3.10.0.04: missing requirement [nexus-core-feature/3.10.0.04] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=nexus-repository-r; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.0.1,1.0.1]" [caused by: Unable to resolve nexus-repository-r/1.0.1: missing requirement [nexus-repository-r/1.0.1] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.0.1,1.0.1]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r/1.0.1: missing requirement [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r/1.0.1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.commons.compress.archivers)(version>=1.11.0))"]]]
```

What can be wrong?
Thanks

Comment: IIRC everytime there's a NXRM3 release something in the plugin needs updated to point to the new release.  You might follow up on the team gitter to see if anyone has any better ideas: https://gitter.im/sonatype/nexus-oss